# How to show alert notification in tailwind?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, react-portal

I want to display a notification by using Tailwind CSS and use of `createPortal` feature of React JS. I have a component named `Message` where I added my alert HTML code and my div with id `toast-message`is in `_document.tsx` file.

My Message Component:

```
const Message = ({ text, type }: { text: string; type: string }) => {
  return isClientWindow
    ? createPortal(
        <div className={`alert alert-${type} shadow-lg`}>
          <div>
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              fill="none"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              className="stroke-current flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6"
            >
              <path
                strokeLinecap="round"
                strokeLinejoin="round"
                strokeWidth="2"
                d="M13 16h-1v-4h-1m1-4h.01M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"
              ></path>
            </svg>
            <span>{text}</span>
          </div>
        </div>,
        document.querySelector("#toast-message") as HTMLElement
      )
    : "";
};

export default {
  info(text: string) {
    return Message({ text: text, type: "info" });
  },
  success(text: string) {
    return Message({ text: text, type: "success" });
  },
  warn(text: string) {
    return Message({ text: text, type: "warning" });
  },
  error(text: string) {
    return Message({ text: text, type: "error" });
  },
};
```

I want this alert notification by calling my message component like this: `Message.success("Success Message")`. when i call like this from api response it is not rendering however my message is passed to the component. Can someone explain me what is the issue and how to do it.

Comment: You cannot call a React component as you do in the various functions at the end, you need to render it somewhere in your app.

Comment: Also, unless you really want to reinvent the wheel, you could simply use a library like react-toastify that already does that. Even if you want to write your own, you can get inspiration from their API, for instance you need to render a ToastContainer in your app somewhere.